# What are the disadvantages of using reverse scan index in db2 LUW?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

Since DB2 LUW V9.1,the reverse scans are enabled by default for index. This  [link](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0061100.html) talks about the advantages of using reverse scan.

Are there any scenarios where it is better off to disable the reverse scan by default in the index ?

Answer (score 0):

Each leaf page in an index contains stores the address of the next leaf page, in order to allow forward scans. When you enable reverse scans, DB2 stores the address of the previous leaf page.

There are certainly theoretical edge cases where maintaining both forward and reverse pointers might be noticeable; and if NO queries EVER use a reverse index scan then it might be something to consider.  But I suspect that this would be a very rare combination.